# Serverless command "wsgi serve" not found

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, npm, server, serverless-framework

I am trying to run 'sls wsgi serve' to start the server. I tried to install it with  `npm i serverless-wsgi` and `sls plugin install -n serverless-wsgi`. It says **Successfully installed "serverless-wsgi@latest"** but after running it Serverless command "wsgi serve" not found.

I am using Ubuntu 20.04.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the problem with running **sudo npm install -g serverless@1.68.0**